# x86 assembly - masm32: Issues with waiting for response

Tags: assembly, input, x86, masm, masm32

I have created this program that takes two inputs and prints them out (simple, yes, but it's for practise). It compiles, and runs fine, but it doesn't do what I intended. Here is my code:

```
.386 
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap :none 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
.data 
   num1 db "Enter a number:", 0 
   num2 db "Enter another number:", 0
.data? 
       buffer1 dd 100 dup(?)
   buffer2 dd 100 dup(?)
.code 
start:
   lea eax, num1
   push eax
   call StdOut
   lea ebx, buffer1
   push ebx
   call StdIn
   hlt
   lea eax, num2
   push eax
   call StdOut
   lea edx, buffer2
   push edx
   call StdIn
   xor eax, eax
   xor ebx, ebx
   xor edx, edx
   lea eax, buffer1
   push eax
   call StdOut
   lea ebx, buffer2
   push ebx
   call StdOut
   push 0 
   call ExitProcess
end start
```

It displays this output:

```
Enter a number: Enter another number:
```

It should do:

```
Enter a number:
; wait for input.
Enter another number:
; wait for input.
; continue with program.
```

Why does it print on one line? I tried putting `halt` in there to stop the process, but Windows stops the program from running, and says `the program is not responding`.

EDIT:

Here is the code that I said I would edit in:

```
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor edx, edx
lea eax, buffer1
push eax
call StdOut
lea ebx, buffer2
push ebx
call StdOut
```

When I run this with the previous code, it says `"This program is not responding."` Why is this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Progrmr

Comment: Why wouldn't it print all on one line?  Thats what it does, you have to add 13, 10 after your text.  Also your buffer to hold text should be db not dd unless you really want a 400 byte buffer.

Comment: That shifts it to another line, thanks. But it still doesn't wait for input, it shows both num1 and num2 and then doesn't wait for input. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hlt will, plainly, halt execution. It should only be used to wait for the next hardware interrupt, and should only be used by the operating system.

StdIn isn't working for you, because you aren't providing the length of buffer. So StdIn fails and the next StdOut is executed.

Don't use hlt, and push the length of buffer and then push the address to buffer.

```
.386 
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap :none 

include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc 
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
include \MASM32\INCLUDE\user32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
includelib \MASM32\LIB\user32.lib

atoi PROTO C strptr:DWORD

.data 
   num1 db "Enter a number:", 0 
   num2 db "Enter another number:", 0
   formatStr db "%s+%s=%d", 0

.data? 
   buffer1 dw 100 dup(?)
   buffer2 dw 100 dup(?)
   buffer3 dw 100 dup(?)
.code 
start:
   lea eax, num1
   push eax
   call StdOut

   mov eax,100
   push eax
   lea eax, buffer1
   push eax
   call StdIn

   lea eax, num2
   push eax
   call StdOut

   mov eax,100
   push eax
   lea eax, buffer2
   push eax
   call StdIn

   lea eax, buffer1
   push eax
   call atoi
   mov ebx,eax

   lea eax, buffer2
   push eax
   call atoi 
   add eax,ebx

   push eax
   lea eax,buffer2
   push eax
   lea eax,buffer1
   push eax
   lea eax,formatStr
   push eax
   lea eax,buffer3
   push eax
   call wsprintf


   lea eax,buffer3
   push eax
   call StdOut

   push 0 
   call ExitProcess

end start
```

Output:
[image: Output]

stdcall dictates you push parameters from right to left.
Also, you might benefit from reviewing the code for StdIn and StdOut:

```
StdIn proc lpszBuffer:DWORD,bLen:DWORD

   LOCAL hInput :DWORD
   LOCAL bRead  :DWORD

   invoke GetStdHandle,STD_INPUT_HANDLE
   mov hInput, eax

   invoke SetConsoleMode,hInput,ENABLE_LINE_INPUT or \
                                ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT or \
                                ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT

   invoke ReadFile,hInput,lpszBuffer,bLen,ADDR bRead,NULL

   mov eax, bRead

   ret

StdIn endp

StdOut proc lpszText:DWORD

    LOCAL hOutPut  :DWORD
    LOCAL bWritten :DWORD
    LOCAL sl       :DWORD

    invoke GetStdHandle,STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov hOutPut, eax

    invoke StrLen,lpszText
    mov sl, eax

    invoke WriteFile,hOutPut,lpszText,sl,ADDR bWritten,NULL

    mov eax, bWritten
    ret

StdOut endp
```

Comment: Thanks Motes. One last question: when I ran the code, it worked a treat. But when the program came to the part where it prints the inputs, it says `This program is not responding. My code that follows your example is edited into the post. Can you help me?

Comment: Are your sure you removed the hlt instruction? Also, there is no need to use multiple registers or to clear them with xor. I updated the code I provided to supply a full working example, along with output.